# How To Filter 1:N Add Existing Lookup Dynamics CRM 2013?

Tags: javascript, crm, dynamics-crm-2013

Do you know how can we filter 1:N "Add Existing Lookup"  at Dynamics CRM 2013 ?

We tried this part, but it doesnt work anymore in CRM 2013:

```
var lookupItems = LookupObjects(null, "multi", gridTypeCode, 0, null, "", null, null, null, null, null, null, viewId, [customView]);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should change your LookupObjects function to LookupObjectsWithCallback function:

```
LookupObjectsWithCallback(callbackReference, null, "multi", gridTypeCode, 0, null, "", null, null, null, null, null, null, viewId, [customView]);
```

Where your `callbackReference` is an object with property `callback`:

```
callbackReference: {
   callback: function (lookupItems) {    
          // Do something with selected items.
   }
}
```