# addCustomView in CRM 2013 lookup

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013

I get an **Savedquery With Id = 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 Does Not Exist** message when I set up the custom view to a CRM 2013 Team lookup, whit this code, working in CRM 2011.

```
// Set the Owning Team View based on the account selected
function setOwningTeamView(entityFieldName, lookupFieldName, resetSelection) {
  // Get the selected entity 
  var account = Xrm.Page.getAttribute(entityFieldName).getValue();

if (account != null) {
    var accid = account[0].id;
    var accname = account[0].name;

    if (resetSelection == true) {
        // reset old selection for Contact
        Xrm.Page.getAttribute(lookupFieldName).setValue(null);
    }

    // use randomly generated GUID Id for the view
    var viewId = "{0CBC820C-7033-4AFF-9CE8-FB610464DBD3}";
    var entityName = "team";

    // give the custom view a name
    var viewDisplayName = "Teams applicable to " + accname + "";

    var accountBU = SDK.REST.retrieveRecordSync(Xrm.Page.getAttribute("a_account").getValue()[0].id, "Account", "OwningBusinessUnit", "");
    var relatedBusinessUnits = SDK.REST.retrieveMultipleRecordsSync("BusinessUnit", "?$select=BusinessUnitId,Name&$filter=a_Type/Value eq 1");
    var FetchXMLBU = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < relatedBusinessUnits.results.length; i++) {
        FetchXMLBU += "<value>" + relatedBusinessUnits.results[i].BusinessUnitId + "</value>"
    }

    debugger;

    // find all contacts where parent customer is the account selected and where the Contact record is active
    var fetchXml = "<fetch version='1.0' output-format='xml-platform' mapping='logical' distinct='false'>"
        + "<entity name='team'>"
        + "<attribute name='teamid' />"
        + "<attribute name='name' />"
        + "<attribute name='description' />"
        + "<attribute name='businessunitid' />"
        + "<filter>"
        + "<condition attribute='businessunitid' operator='in'>"
        + "<value>" + accountBU.OwningBusinessUnit.Id + "</value>"
        + FetchXMLBU
        + "</condition>"
        + "</filter>"
        + "</entity>"
        + "</fetch>";

    // build Grid Layout
    var layoutXml = "<grid name='resultset' " +
        "object='1' " +
        "jump='teamid' " +
        "select='1' " +
        "icon='0' " +
        "preview='0'>" +
        "<row name='result' id='teamid'>" +
        "<cell name='name' width='200' />" +
        "<cell name='businessunitid' width='200' />" +
        "<cell name='description' width='400' />" +
        "</row>" +
        "</grid>";

    // add the Custom View to the indicated [lookupFieldName] Control
    Xrm.Page.getControl(lookupFieldName).addCustomView(viewId, entityName, viewDisplayName, fetchXml, layoutXml, true);
    //The following line is the an unsupported way of disabling the View Picker, currently there is no supported way.
    document.getElementById(lookupFieldName + "_i").setAttribute("disableViewPicker", "1");
    //document.getElementById(lookupFieldName).setAttribute("disableViewPicker", "1");
}
}
```

I suspect that the problem with be with the calls to **SDK.REST** as explained [in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21313363/how-to-filter-1n-add-existing-lookup-dynamics-crm-2013), but results in **accountBU** and  **relatedBusinessUnits** are correct.

I have using another SDK call aith a correct behavior as:

```
 var systemUserTeam = SDK.REST.retrieveMultipleRecordsSync("TeamMembership",
                "$select=TeamId&$filter=TeamId eq guid'"
                + Xrm.Page.getAttribute("aux_owningteamid").getValue()[0].id
                + "' and SystemUserId eq guid'"
                + Xrm.Page.getAttribute("ownerid").getValue()[0].id
                + "'");
    if (systemUserTeam.results.length != 1) {
```

I'm setting up a **Customer** lookup view with custom **fetchXML** and **laoyoutXML** with same method **except** for the calls to SDK.

Which change could I do to the SDK call to get it working?

Answer (score 2):

If you're not averse to rewriting the code there's now an easier and supported way of adding custom filters to a lookup.  You could use an existing view and apply the preFilter.

[This blog post](http://community.dynamics.com/crm/b/magnetismsolutionscrmblog/archive/2013/09/30/crm-2013-javascript-lookup-filtering-using-addcustomfilter.aspx) provides a good example.

Comment: Thanks, I already checked that blog, but in my case,as I need a custom view I'll have to use addCustomView

Answer (score 1):

`addCustomView` doesn’t work with `Owner` lookups. `Owner` lookups are used to assign user-owned records.

Link - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334266.aspx#BKMK_addCustomView

Comment: Could you please provide a bit more information? As it stands, your post is more a comment than a real answer...

Comment: @Badacadabra - You can create a custom field, the system field "ownerid" to make invisible on the form.
In the custom field, implement the desired "addCustomView" and on the server through a plugin make "AssignRequest".

Answer (score 0):

It is probably the object='1' in your layoutxml- objecttypecode of 1 means you are trying to create the view on account, when you need to create it on team. So CRM is making the custom view against account and they trying to call it against team. Team I believe is 9. That change should hopefully all else been right, have you sorted. If it isn't nine download and install the DynamicsXRMtools solution and check the CRM metadata.